addCustomFilter function not working in dynamics 365
I am trying to apply a custom filter on a lookup attribute.
The fetchXML returns correct values then why addCustomFilter is not working? I have turned off the related records filtering as well.
I have tried everything. The function fires up and doesn't throw any errors.
function filterClassificationValues() {
    var fetchXML = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='db_mailboxname' operator='eq' value='{guid of the record}' /></filter>";
    formContext.getControl("nameOfTheField").addCustomFilter(fetchXML, "entityName");
}

//this function is called On Load
function AddPreSearch(executionContext) {
    formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    formContext.getControl("nameOfTheField").addPreSearch(filterClassificationValues);
}


Probably the formContext in function filterClassificationValues is out of scope or sync.
Simplify the code like this:
function addPreSearch(executionContext) {
    const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    const fetchXml = `<filter type='and'><condition attribute='db_mailboxname' operator='eq' value='${formContext.data.entity.getId()}' /></filter>`;
    const control = formContext.getControl("nameOfTheField");

    control.addPreSearch(function () {
        control.addCustomFilter(fetchXml, "entityName");
    });
}


No, I also retrieve logged in user's id and associated mailbox using form context in filterClassificationValues and it gives correct values
